# How to compare the value of rows in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following dataframe

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F1 | F2 | 0 |
| F1 | F3 | 2 |
| F1 | F2 | 1 |
| F1 | F4 | 4 |
| F1 | F3 | 1 |

and want to convert this into the following

| X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F1 | F2 | 0 |
| F1 | F4 | 4 |
| F1 | F3 | 1 |

Here i want to remove the rows that have same values in X and Y columns keeping the one whose value in the Z column is lowest. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```py
# index of smallest Z values per X-Y pair
idx = df.groupby(['X', 'Y'])['Z'].idxmin().sort_values()
# filter
df.loc[idx]
```

[image]